# function modifies 2d array (struct) parameter

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, malloc

The following function addhalf() in the C program takes a 2d-array of type Frac (fractions) with same number of rows and columns, as well as the corresponding length. In main(), I dynamically allocated memory for a 2d-array of fractions using a double pointer and malloc.

The values of the 2d array are printed before, during, and after function call.

My goal was to pass in a 2d struct array without having it modified, specifically using the double pointer method to allocate memory for it.

How come the original parameter was modified in main() after calling addhalf(), as seen in the output below?

Thanks for any help.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "fraction.h"

void addhalf(Frac** f, int len)
{
    while (f[0][0].n < f[0][0].d)
    {
        printf("In function: \n");
        for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < len; j++)
            {
                Frac h;
                h.n = 1;
                h.d = 2;
                f[i][j] = add(f[i][j], h);
                printf("%d/%d, ",f[i][j].n, f[i][j].d);
            }
            printf("\n");           
        }
        printf("------\n\n");
        addhalf(f, len);
    }
}

int main()
{
    int size = 3;
    Frac** arr  = (Frac**) malloc(sizeof(Frac*) * size);
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        arr[i] = (Frac*) malloc(sizeof(Frac) * size);
    }

    printf("Original: \n");
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < size; j++)
        {
            arr[i][j].n = 1;
            arr[i][j].d = 3;
            printf("%d/%d, ",arr[i][j].n, arr[i][j].d);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    printf("------\n\n");

    // this should not modify the parameter (arr), but
    // it does anyways
    addhalf(arr, size);

    printf("Original: \n");
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < size; j++)
        {
            printf("%d/%d, ",arr[i][j].n, arr[i][j].d);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

fraction.h:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#ifndef __FRACTION_H
#define __FRACTION_H

struct Frac_struct {
   int n;
   int d;
};
typedef struct Frac_struct Frac;

int gcd(int x, int y);

Frac simplify(Frac a);

Frac add(Frac a, Frac b);

Frac sub(Frac a, Frac b);

Frac mul(Frac a, Frac b);

Frac divide(Frac a, Frac b);

Frac neg(Frac a);

#endif /* __FRACTION_H */
```

Output executing Program:

```
Original:
1/3, 1/3, 1/3,
1/3, 1/3, 1/3,
1/3, 1/3, 1/3,
------

In function:
5/6, 5/6, 5/6,
5/6, 5/6, 5/6,
5/6, 5/6, 5/6,
------

In function:
4/3, 4/3, 4/3,
4/3, 4/3, 4/3,
4/3, 4/3, 4/3,
------

Original:
4/3, 4/3, 4/3,
4/3, 4/3, 4/3,
4/3, 4/3, 4/3,
```

Comment: *"despite not using any reference operators"*. That's not a correct statement. `f[i][j]` is a dereference operation. It's just that the compiler is doing it for you.

Comment: Would that explain why my parameter was modified through the function? I.e. double pointers are pass by reference?

Comment: Yes but not in the way you explained it. *All* parameters are passed by value in C. There is just technically no such thing as pass by reference in C. You are passing the *pointer* by value. So the actual thing you are passing in, the pointer value (ie the memory address), can never be changed. But the thing it *points to* can be changed.

Comment: And it is not 2d array you are using, it is array of pointers to arrays. For the pass by reference thing, if someone have a copy of your credit card, he/she can't screw your card, but your money